# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

**ViewModel**

```
public class EmployeeIndexViewModel {
    public int selectedDepartment { get; set; }
    public IList departments1 { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
List<Department> list = new List<Department>();
list.Add(new Department { ID = 1, Name = "D1" });
list.Add(new Department { ID = 2, Name = "D2" });
list.Add(new Department { ID = 3, Name = "D3" });
employeeIndexViewModel.departments1 = list;
employeeIndexViewModel.selectedDepartment = "2";
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.department, new SelectList(Model.departments1, "Id", "Name"))
```

Now,the coding is working fine. But I do not like this piece

```
new SelectList(Model.departments1, "Id", "Name")
```

I want to add it to my view model, then just bind it in my view.
So I changed my ViewModel

**new ViewModel**

```
public class EmployeeIndexViewModel {
    public int selectedDepartment { get; set; }
    public IList departments1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> departments2 { get; set; }//add this
}
```

**new Controller Action**

```
List<Department> list = new List<Department>();
list.Add(new Department { ID = 1, Name = "D1" });
list.Add(new Department { ID = 2, Name = "D2" });
list.Add(new Department { ID = 3, Name = "D3" });
employeeIndexViewModel.departments1 = list;
employeeIndexViewModel.selectedDepartment = "2";
employeeIndex2ViewModel.departments2 = new SelectList(list, "id", "name");// add this
```

**new view**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.department, new SelectList(Model.departments1, "Id", "Name"))
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.department, (SelectList)(m => m.departments2))//add this
```

I got this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: It just needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.department, Model.departments2)`. Please also note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the lambda expression in your new view
 `(SelectList)(m => m.departments2)` and replace it with `Model.departments2`

Comment: Its already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - there is no need to cast it

Comment: Thanks for your help. Stephen and Nadeem